# convert datetime to date python --> error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime, jupyter-notebook

Pandas by default represent dates with datetime64 [ns], so I have in my columns this format         [2016-02-05 00:00:00] but I just want the date 2016-02-05, so I applied this code for a few columns:

```
df3a['MA'] = pd.to_datetime(df3a['MA'])
df3a['BA'] = pd.to_datetime(df3a['BA'])
df3a['FF'] = pd.to_datetime(df3a['FF'])
df3a['JJ'] = pd.to_datetime(df3a['JJ'])
.....
```

but it gives me as result this error: TypeError: type unhashable: 'numpy.ndarray'
my question is: why i got this error and how do i convert datetime to date for multiple columns (around 50)?

i will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you'd like is with a DatetimeIndex. I've first created an Example DataFrame with  'date' and 'values' columns and tried from there on to reproduce the error you've got.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex (dti)
dti = pd.date_range('2020-12-01','2020-12-17')     # dates from first of december up to date
values = np.random.choice(range(1, 101), len(dti)) # random values between 1 and 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dti,'values':values}, index=range(len(dti)))

print(df.head())
>>>          date  values
     0 2020-12-01      85
     1 2020-12-02     100
     2 2020-12-03      96
     3 2020-12-04      40
     4 2020-12-05      27
```

In the example, just the dates are already shown without the time in the 'date' column, I guess since it is a DatetimeIndex.

What I haven't tested but might can work for you is:

```
# Your dataframe
df3a['MA'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3a['MA'])
...

# automated transform for all columns (if all columns are datetimes!)
for label in df3a.columns:
    df3a[label] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3a[label])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
cols = ['MA', 'BA', 'FF', 'JJ']

df3a[cols] = df3a[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```